# Interactive Ssh blocked with Catalina

Tags: ssh, catalina

Since migrating to Catalina, I am not able to run an interactive shell through SSH to one of my linux servers. Using a Windows machine (I do not have a pre-Catalina machine available), I have no problem connecting.

Non-interactive ssh works correctly (I use an authorized key, so no password prompt) :

```
~> echo 'uname -a' | ssh user@server
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Linux ????? 4.9.78-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #2 SMP Wed Jan 24 10:27:15 CET 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Interactive ssh hangs, until the server's sshd kick me out :

```
~> ssh user@server
[Long wait]
packet_write_wait: Connection to ????: Broken pipe
```

When use verbose (-v), I can see that the authentication works:

```
~> ssh -v user@server
[...]
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)
[...]
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
[long Wait]
packet_write_wait: Connection to ????: Broken pipe
```

Not using a authorized key results in a password prompt, and then the same `Broken pipe`

Versions:

```
~> sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.1
BuildVersion:   19B88

~> ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the difference between your first and your second example, seem to be the same? Does a pure `ssh user@server` work? Does `ssh user@server uname -a` work?

Comment: @nohillside, indeed. Thanks for noticing, I've just corrected it

Comment: And yes direct command input (no Stdin) does the same : 

    ~> ssh user@server uname -a

    Linux ???? 4.9.78-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #2 SMP Wed Jan 24 10:27:15 CET 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but you can `ssh -vvv ... ` to get even more info

Answer (score 1):

After looking some more I found a workaround [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/590825) and on [superUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1425434/ssh-broken-pipe)

Adding `-o IPQoS=throughput` to the ssh command line fixed my issue :

```
ssh -o IPQoS=throughput user@server
```

It's ugly to have to add this option, even if it could probably be added in `~/.ssh/config`. It also probably hides some other issues. Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: true. I was hopping someone more knowledgeful would create another answer (or modify this one) to give a more complete understanding

Comment: Even if `-o IPQoS=throughput` was added, ssh login was still stuck at `Sending env LANG = zh_CN.UTF-8`,and finally got `packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx port xx: Broken pipe`. ssh -V OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround did work for me, and so did using `-T` to `Disable pseudo-terminal allocation`.

But after updating to the latest macOS and restarting the issue went away altogether...